# Injeção de dependência no controller com Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, injeção-de-dependência, castle-windsor

Boa tarde, estou usando ASP.NET MVC 5 com Windsor e quando uma requisição Ajax chama um método no controller, da erro informando que o controller tem dependências não satisfeitas. Como faço pra funcionar a requisição já que as dependências são resolvidas no construtor?

No Controller declaro as variáveis:

```
    private readonly IMaterial _material;
    private readonly IFamilia _familia;
    private readonly IUnidade _unidade;
    private readonly IAlterarMaterial _alterarMaterial;
```

Depois tenho o contrutor do Controller:

```
public MaterialController(IMaterial material, IFamilia familia, IUnidade unidade, IAlterarMaterial alterarMaterial)
        {
            _material = material;
            _unidade = unidade;
            _familia = familia;
            _alterarMaterial = alterarMaterial;
        }
```

E depois tenho o método que será chamado pelo Ajax.

```
public ActionResult ListarMaterial(String nome)
        {
            List<Material> lista = _material.Listar(nome).ToList();
            return View(lista);
        }
```

No Global.asax tenho esses dois metodos

```
private static void RegisterWindsor()
        {
            container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

            var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
        }

        protected void Application_End()
        {
            container.Dispose();
        }
```

E no applications_Start

```
RegisterWindsor();
```

Classe ControllerFactory

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IKernel kernel;

        public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
        {
            this.kernel = kernel;
        }

        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
            }
            return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
    }
```

Chamado Ajax

```
function Pesquisar() {
        $('.corpoTbl').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Material/ListarMaterial",
            type: "POST",
            data: { nome: $('#pesquisa').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.ok){
                    window.alert("erro");
                }
                else {
                    $('#tabela').html(data);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Poderia postar uma parte do seu código para entendermos como é feita essa injeção de dependência?

Comment: Faltou o comando usando para o Windsor atuar.

Comment: E qual comando seria esse?

Comment: Não sei. Você precisou configurar o Windsor. É isso que quero saber.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei os arquivos de configuração do Windsor, quando utilizo o sistema normalmente e as requisições são feitas do modo tradicional, ou seja, pelo formulário da pagina, funciona normalmente, só quando faço uma requisição Ajax que não funciona.

Comment: Aparentemente está tudo certo. Como é a chamada para o Ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Por este tutorial aqui](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2009/03/28/ASPNET-MVC-with-Windsor-programmatic-controller-registration.aspx), acho que faltaram algumas coisas. Deveria estar funcionando, mas aparentemente o ASP.NET MVC se perde em algum lugar na hora de construir *Controllers* para o Ajax.

## Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{
    // Troque isto
    // RegisterWindsor();
    // Por isto
    CreateWindsorContainer();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    RegisterControllers();
    RegisterControllerFactory(); // Coloque este método
}

void RegisterControllerFactory() {
   container.Register(
     Component
       .For<IControllerFactory>()
       .ImplementedBy<WindsorControllerFactory>()
       .LifeStyle.Singleton
     );
   var controllerFactory = container.Resolve<IControllerFactory>();
   ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
 }

 static void CreateWindsorContainer() {
   container = new WindsorContainer();
   // new: register the container with itself 
   //      to be able to resolve the dependency in the ctor
   //      of WindsorControllerFactory
   container.Register(
     Component
       .For<IWindsorContainer>()
       .Instance(container)
     );
 }  

static void RegisterControllers() {
   container.Register(
     AllTypes
       .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
       .BasedOn<IController>()
     );
 }
```

Comment: Refiz todas as configurações do Windsor, e fiz como você disse na resposta acima a agora ta funcionando.